# Visual Studio Online one project Team members can access other projects?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, collaboration

I have created a bunch of projects in my Visual Studio Online account. For one of these projects, let's call it "Public project", I have invited other participants.

But when I work with other projects (which "Team members" consist on me myself only) I noticed, that when I create a bug (for instance) I can assign it to any of "Public project" participants.

Is this a bug of Visual Studio Online, or is it intended behaviour? If Yes, then why? For now I didn't manage to find any information about this behaviour/bug...

I just want to keep my private stuff private and not to mess it with my team stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug based on the current design.  The list of available identities that work items can be assigned to is populated with the list of available identities in your entire Visual Studio Online account.  It's not limited to only the team members in that team project.  It doesn't mean that those users have access to source code, work items, etc. in your private projects if you haven't given them permissions.

During the deployment that's going on now, we invested in a better experience for choosing identities.  You can see more details about those improvements here:  http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-dec-2-vso

[image: New Identity Improvements in Visual Studio Online]